# Passing data from a component to another

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have a component which retrieve datas from a user. 
the object is composed with id, username and email. 
I have a component for editing those values and for updating them.

In the parent component "parentComponent" i retrieve the datas from an URL :

```
getUser(event) {
    /*Check for validations on input and then call the api
    let validFlag = !isNaN(this.userId);
    if (validFlag) {
        axios
          .get("http://localhost:4000/api/users/" + this.userId)
          .then(response => {
          console.log(response);
          this.user = response.data.data;
          /*If needed to clear the userId*/
          this.userId = "";
         });
         } else {
           /*input value is not a number -do something about it (alert/notify)*/
           this.userId = "";
           this.isExistingUser = !this.isExistingUser;
           console.log("User do not exist : " + this.isExistingUser)
        }
     }
},
```

This method allow me to display the information in the ParentComponent :

```
<th scope="row"> {{ user["id"] }}</th>
<td>{{ user["username"] }}</td>
<td>{{ user["email"] }} </td>
```

My objective is to pass the user to a child component. That's why I define a props in the "ParentComponent" :

```
props: {
    userToEdit: {
       type: Object,
       default: {
            editIUsername: this.username,
            editIEmail: this.email
        }
    }
},
```

In the template i bind the UserToEdit :

```
<child-component v-bind="userToEdit"></child-component>
```

In fact i'm unable to retrieve data in the child-component and i receive error messages such as and i'm looking how i can pass the "id" too to the child component :

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined

Comment: This might be helpful, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56155690/vuejs-access-parent-prop-in-child-when-the-child-is-visited-directly-using-vue

Comment: I watched it ... but it doesn't fit my issue unfortunatelly